# how to iterate over tensorflow tensor_list referencing both index and individual tensor

Tags: tensorflow, lambda, enumerate

I tried following code, used tf.map_fn, and still got error as: *"Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn."*

```
def get_tensor_A(i):
    return mask[i]   #another tensor returned

def get_tensor_B(x):
    return tf.nn.softmax(x, 1)

def final_rt(i, inp):
    return get_tensor_A(idx)*get_tensor_B(inp)

tensor_2_list = [ tf.map_fn(lambda x: final_rt(x(0), x(1)), (idx, inp))  for idx, inp in enumerate(tensor_1_list)]
```